# How can I create a bar plot without 'fill' in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have a dataframe which contains data like below

```
     Monsoon                 F_Monsoon                         avg_Min_temp_year
  1 Post-Monsoon Autumn    avg_Min_temp                                 21.4
  2 Pre-Monsoon Hot Summer avg_Min_temp                                 22.5
  3 Rainy                  avg_Min_temp                                 25.6
  4 Winter                 avg_Min_temp                                 13.9
  5 Post-Monsoon Autumn    avg_Min_temp_monsoon                         20.7
  6 Pre-Monsoon Hot Summer avg_Min_temp_monsoon                         22.1
  ...
  ...
```

I am trying to create a plot without any color (only black and white)

My code is given below

```
plot <- ggplot(plot_final_df, aes(Monsoon, avg_Min_temp_year))+
 geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")+
 theme_bw()+
 facet_wrap(~Monsoon)+
 theme(panel.grid = element_blank())+
 xlab("Monsoon")+
 ylab("Avg Min Temp")+
 ggtitle("Avg Min Temp vs Monsoon")
```

My plot is showing only `one bar` for each `monsoon` but it must show `2 bar (one for avg_Min_temp and for avg_Min_temp_monsoon)`

When I am using `fill` properties inside `aes(fill = F_Monsoon)` it is showing `2 bar for each monsoon` with color but I need `black and white`

Any kind of suggestion is appreciable.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(plot_final_df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(plot_final_df, 20))`. Also, instead of `fill` try `group`.

Comment: Hello, thanks, `group` worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already faceting by `Monsoon`, and you want each facet to contain to have two bars (one each for both levels in `F_Monsoon`, you should have `F_Monsoon` as the x axis:

```r
ggplot(plot_final_df, aes(F_Monsoon, avg_Min_temp_year)) +
 geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
 facet_wrap(~Monsoon) +
 theme_bw() +
 theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) +
 xlab("Monsoon") +
 ylab("Avg Min Temp") +
 ggtitle("Avg Min Temp vs Monsoon")
```

[image]

Note I had to add two extra rows to your example data to get this to work:

**Data**

```r
plot_final_df <- structure(list(Monsoon = c("Post-Monsoon Autumn", 
"Pre-Monsoon Hot Summer", 
"Rainy", "Winter", "Post-Monsoon Autumn", "Pre-Monsoon Hot Summer", 
"Rainy", "Winter"), F_Monsoon = c("avg_Min_temp", "avg_Min_temp", 
"avg_Min_temp", "avg_Min_temp", "avg_Min_temp_monsoon", "avg_Min_temp_monsoon", 
"avg_Min_temp_monsoon", "avg_Min_temp_monsoon"), avg_Min_temp_year = c(21.4, 
22.5, 25.6, 13.9, 20.7, 22.1, 24.6, 12.9)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I got my mistakes!